# Finding Number of Edges on Strongly Connected Component

Tags: python, graph, networkx, edges, connected-components

I have a network graph by name Gmedium, and I've found the largest strongly connected component by this code:

```
maxstmed = max(nx.strongly_connected_components(Gmedium), key=len)
```

My question is, how do you find number of edges of this connected network? If you try to find the number of nodes, I have it like this:

```
newGm = nx.Graph()
newGm.add_nodes_from(list(maxstmed))
newGm.number_of_nodes()
```

But you can't apply this for edges, as it returns 0 when I used add_edges_from and number_of_edges. I tried to count it manually by this:

```
count = 0
for u in list(newGm.nodes):
    for v in list(newGm.nodes):
        if u == v:
            continue
        if nx.has_path(Gmedium,u,v) == True:
            count += 1
print(count)
```

But, for a big network (with over 10.000 nodes), it takes forever. Anyone knows the algorithm or function to handle it efficiently? I am using Python Ver. 3 in Spyder environment. Thank you.

Comment: In addition to @vurmux's answer, you might look at `max_connected_component_subgraph`.  Also, for finding the number of nodes, if you've already got `maxstmed`, there's no need to create a graph that contains all of the nodes in `maxstmed`.  You just need to check how long `maxstmed` is.

Comment: and `nx.has_path` is going to tell you if there is a path from `u` to `v`, not if there is an edge from `u` to `v`.   So I can guarantee you that the answer you're going to get with your code is always n*(n-1) where n is the number of nodes, but that's not the number of edges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`subgraph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.subgraph.html#networkx.DiGraph.subgraph) function to extract a subgraph with given nodes from the original graph. You send a collection of nodes as attribute and it returns you a subgraph of original graph with these nodes and edges between them:

```
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(30, 0.04, directed=True, seed=1)
nx.draw(G)
```

[image]

```
C = max(nx.strongly_connected_components(G), key=len)
print(C)
```

> `{0, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 15, 21, 22, 24, 25}`

```
S = G.subgraph(C)
nx.draw(S)
```

[image]

```
print(list(nx.edges(S)))
```

> `[(0, 3), (3, 4), (3, 21), (4, 6), (6, 11), (6, 15), (8, 0), (10, 6), (11, 8), (11, 15), (15, 24), (15, 25), (21, 8), (21, 22), (21, 15), (22, 24), (22, 25), (22, 15), (24, 10), (25, 0)]`

Comment: Is this can be applied for directed and undirected graph? I meant, for directed graph, if node 0 has directed links to 3 and vice-versa, will it count for 2 edges or just 1 edge?

Comment: Subgraphs can be extracted from any type of graph. But strongly connected components are implemented only for directed graphs. P.S. In your case it will count 2 edges.